# Who are all the characters Tomoko imagines in episode 7?

Tags: watamote

In episode 7 of *Watamote*, when Tomoko is in line to see the otome Voice Actor from the game, she gets the bonus ticket to get a custom recording. She rethinks about what line she wanted after hearing the girl in front of her request the line "I want to ruin you".

Tomoko has a montage of different characters from different anime with the Voice Actor as that character, below is the scene.

[image]

I only know 1 of the shots which is [Heisuke](http://hakuouki.wikia.com/wiki/Heisuke_Toudou) from *Hakuouki* (end of the third row) as he is the only member of the Shinsengumi who has long hair which is tried from the top of the head

I am wondering who were the other characters Tomoko imagined and which anime they came from?

Comment: If they all share *seiyuu* (in reality), you might be able to find some by looking at [Heisuke's *seiyuu* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiroyuki_Yoshino_(voice_actor)).

Comment: @キルア i don't see Watamote on the list so unless they left Hiroyuki Yoshino off because it was a minor role or it's a parody of him there's quite a large number of titles for me along to look though and try and match scenes (considering Heisuke looks much older thanks to Tomoko superimposing the voice actor's face)